# System Call (Read/Write Vs ioctl)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system, system-calls

Which one is faster in terms of Performance used for benchmark I/O (RAW) Read/Write Vs ioctl in linux? why and How?

Regards,
Srinivasa Raghavan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that `read/write` syscalls are faster just because of fact that `ioctl` should analyze request code first and then call the same function as `read/write` syscalls do.